# CVXR Iteration Limit

Tags: cvxpy, cvx, cvxr

Using R, I am running a mixed integer optimization which uses the ECOS_BB solver option when using the standard solve or psolve functions for CVXR.

How can I set the max iterations? I have looked everywhere. None of the ECOS_BB native options do anything when I add them to the function call.

I am using version 0.99-3.

Answer (score 0):

With the current `CVXR` 1.0.1 on CRAN, you can use `num_iter` for all solvers.

```
result <- solve(problem, num_iter = 1000)
```

Five common options are documented in [Dealing with Solver-specific Parameters](https://cvxr.rbind.io/cvxr_examples/cvxr_solver-parameters/) but the documentation needs further improvement.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Unfortunately I am using .99-3. Do you know how I would do it with that version as num_iters doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Thanks. Needed to use the control variable.